# How to use comparator for alphanumerical object values in java

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am trying to compare object based on int type and string type.
I am getting correct value as expected when I do using int type but when I am trying with String type that contains alphanumeric values is getting the correct output as expected. This question also related to how string comparison happens in case of alphanumeric string values. Below is the code.

```
package TestJava;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class EmployeeSort implements Comparable<EmployeeSort> {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public EmployeeSort(int id, String Name) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = Name;
    }

    public int compareTo(EmployeeSort o) {
        return (this.id - o.id);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeSort[] emp = new EmployeeSort[5];
        emp[0] = new EmployeeSort(20, "bj20");
        emp[1] = new EmployeeSort(10, "bj10");
        emp[2] = new EmployeeSort(4, "bj4");
        emp[3] = new EmployeeSort(40, "bj40");
        emp[4] = new EmployeeSort(2, "bj2");

        Arrays.sort(emp);
        System.out.println("Comparable Sorting: "+Arrays.toString(emp));
        Arrays.sort(emp, EmployeeSort.ec);
        System.out.println("Comparator Sorting: " + Arrays.toString(emp));
    }

    public static Comparator<EmployeeSort> ec = new Comparator<EmployeeSort>() {

        public int compare(EmployeeSort o1, EmployeeSort o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    };

}
```

Here is the output:

```
Comparable Sorting:
[[id=2, name=bj2], [id=4, name=bj4], [id=10, name=bj10], [id=20, name=bj20], [id=40, name=bj40]]

Comparator Sorting: 
[[id=10, name=bj10], [id=2, name=bj2], [id=20, name=bj20], [id=4, name=bj4], [id=40, name=bj40]]
```

Expected output is:

```
Comparator Sorting: [[id=2, name=bj2], [id=4, name=bj4], [id=10, name=bj10], [id=20, name=bj20], [id=40, name=bj40]]
```

as I want the strings containing numerical parts to be sorted numerically if they have a commpn prefix.

Comment: From Oracle Docs: " String compareTo() compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings"  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: "I am getting correct value as expected" and "getting the correct output as expected". So, what's the problem?

Comment: The current implementation of compareTo is comparing by `id`. How you're comparing in the Comparator is by String.

Comment: Use `Integer.compare(this.id, o.id)` rather than subtraction.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think editting question adding `Comparable<EmployeeSort>` is not best way to solve OP doubt....

Comment: @JordiCastilla I added nothing, I just indented it. The `<EmployeeSort>` was there before, but not shown because it was being interpreted as an HTML tag.

Comment: uhm... really? I will shut up then.... good catch

Comment: Why this question is down voted. Please add the comment for down voting I can explain you better. Please suggest or guide the solution rather than down voting.

Comment: @JBasu it's unclear what you are asking. I commented above: you say that two things work, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Please check the output: here i am adding again for both comparable and compartor:
Here is the output: Comparable Soring: [[id=2, name=bj2], [id=4, name=bj4], [id=10, name=bj10], [id=20, name=bj20], [id=40, name=bj40]]


Comparator Sorting: [[id=10, name=bj10], [id=2, name=bj2], [id=20, name=bj20], [id=4, name=bj4], [id=40, name=bj40]]

see the compartor output it's comparing string names should print  bj2, bj4, bj10,bj20 and bj40  sequence but not printing as expected.

Comment: @JBasu the expected output is the critical thing that you're missing from the question.

Comment: Where should `[id=20, name=bj10]` come from?

Comment: Typing error - Added expected result.

Comment: And why do you expect that output from the `Comparator sorting`?

Comment: @JBasu Marco's comment tells you the problem: how do you think that string can "know" that the strings end with a number, and that it should sort strings numerically? A string can contain *any* sequence of characters; so its ordering is just defined to be the lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Question intention was that How can I sort and compare the String containing numeric values.

Comment: I think you are not catching my question or I am not able to present my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of partial answers are already given in the comments:

- `Arrays.sort(emp);` uses the "native" sorting of your class, i. e. the one it implements in its `compareTo()` method (which should better be implemented as `Integer.compare(this.id, o.id)`).
- `Arrays.sort(emp, EmployeeSort.ec);` uses the given `Comparator` which uses the "normal" string comparison.

If you want a "special" string sorting which splits up the string into numerical and non-numerical parts, you must implement it on your own.

In this case, think about special cases such as `abc1234bc` and `abc134bc` - what about that `bc` at the end?